# jQuery data value with + not correctly retrieved

Tags: jquery, html

If I have an element with

```
data-something="+5"
```

and try:

```
alert($(el).data('something')); //gives 5, not +5...
```

how can I retrieve the original value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote the jquery manual, regarding the extraction of data-attributes for access with .data() -

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the 
>   value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

It looks like your +5 is being interpreted as the positive integer 5.

Comment: I salute your dedication, though

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be by design.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L314

```
data = data === "true" ? true :
data === "false" ? false :
data === "null" ? null :
!jQuery.isNaN( data ) ? parseFloat( data ) :
    rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
    data;
```

It's that `parseFloat`, coercing it into a number:

```
parseFloat('+5') == Number(5)
```

From http://api.jquery.com/data/:

> To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to
>   convert it, use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.